# How to select rows that are not present in another dataframe ith pyspark 2.1.0?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-2.0

## Env

- pyspark 2.1.0

## Context

I have two dataframes with the following structures:

dataframe 1:

```
id | ... | distance
```

dataframe 2:

```
id | ... | distance | other calculated values
```

The second dataframe is created based on a filter of the dataframe 1. This filter selects, from dataframe 1, only the distances <= 30.0.

Note that the dataframe1 will contain the same ID on multiple lines.

## Problem

I need to to select from dataframe 1 rows with an ID that do not appear in the dataframe 2.

The purpose is to select the rows for which ID there is no distance lower or equal to 30.0.

## Tested solution

i have tried the leftanti join, which, according to not official doc but sources on Internet (because, hey, why would they explain it ?): `select all rows from df1 that are not present in df2`

```
distinct_id_thirty = within_thirty_km \
    .select("id") \
    .distinct()
not_within_thirty_km = data_with_straight_distance.join(
        distinct_id_thirty,
        "id",
        "leftanti")
```

Where:

- `within_thrity_km` is a dataframe resulting of the filter `filter(col("distance") <= 30.0)` on `data_with_straight_distance`
- `data_with_straight_distance` is a dataframe containing all the data.
- `distinct_id_thirty` is a dataframe containing a distinct list of IDs from the dataframe `within_thirty_km`

## Question

The above returns data where distance is bellow 30. So I assume I am doing something wrong:

- What am I doing wrong here ?
- Is it the good way to solve this problem ? If not, how should I proceed ?

Edit:

Here is a minimal example of what I expect:

```
data = [
    ("1", 15),
    ("1", 35),
    ("2", 15),
    ("2", 30),
    ("3", 35)]

data = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'distance'])

data.show()

thirty = data.filter(col("distance") <= 30)

dist_thirty = thirty.select("id").distinct()

not_in_thirty = data.join(dist_thirty, "id", "left_anti")

print("thirty")
thirty.show()

print("distinst thirty")
dist_thirty.show()

print("not_in_thirty")
not_in_thirty.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+--------+
| id|distance|
+---+--------+
|  3|      35|
+---+--------+
```

But I do get distance <= 30 where running on my actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"leftanti"` should be replaced by `"left_anti"` following the documentation on:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join

Comment: Do you mean ``data_with_straight_distance.join(distinct_id_thirty, "id", "leftanti").where(isNull('data_with_straight_distance.id'))``
?

Comment: I have to admit I do not understand your answer. What is the link with null IDs ? I have no null ID.

Comment: My bad, my answer was out of scope. I didn't know anti joins where a thing. But when looking at the documentation it seems it should be written "left_anti": https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join

Comment: It seems you are right. It's left_anti, not leftanti. Why doesn't spark throw an error ?

Comment: @thebot: Could you please update your answer, so that it can be upvoted?

Comment: Will do thank you! Yes indeed, that's a bit stupid, maybe a bug..